# How to check GEOIP module in installed in my server

Tags: php, geolocation, geoip

I am using a plugin which uses GEOIP module. I am not sure if this module is installed in my server since this is a shared server.
I need some php script to check if this module is installed or not.
I found this script:

```
$mods = apache_get_modules();

if (array_search('mod_geoip',$mods)){
   print "GEO IP exist";
}else{
   print "GEO IP Doesn't Exist";
}
```

but ended up with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules() in
>   testmodule.php on line 2

Comment: Can't you just run `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem to find out if geoip is installed as an apache-module.
But geoip (as apache-mod) provide some functions to find country codes for example.
Thats the point, you have to check if some geoip-functions exists with php `functions_exists()`.
I've tested this solution by self.
The reason why i use that function is to move my tools over many server with different apache-mods like "geoip" etc. Hope this solution is usefull!?

```
if ( function_exists("geoip_country_code_by_name") ){
    $geoip = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
} else { 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/geoip/geoip.inc");
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/geoip/geoipregionvars.php");
    $gi = geoip_open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/geoip/data/GeoIP.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $geoip = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    geoip_close($geoip);
}
```